# Como converter HTML para RTF?

Tags: c#, html, .net, conversão, rtf

Tenho um projeto em Asp.Net MVC onde gostaria de converter uma string HTML em RTF no Controller.

Já tentei das seguintes formas:

[Fonte 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150208/how-do-i-convert-html-to-rtf-rich-text-in-net-without-paying-for-a-component)

```
using(var webBrowser = new WebBrowser()){
   webBrowser.CreateControl();
   webBrowser.DocumentText = minhaStringHTML;

   while(webBrowser.DocumentText != minhaStringHTML)
   {
       Application.DoEvents();
   }

    webBrowser.Document.ExecCommand("SelectAll", false, null);
    webBrowser.Document.ExecCommand("Copy", false, null);

    using(var rtc = new RichTextBox())
    {
       meuRTF = rtc.Paste();
    }
}
```

Mas logo **na primeira linha** apresentada, obtive o seguinte erro:

> {"Não é possível criar uma instância do controle ActiveX
>   '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' porque o thread atual não está
>   em um STA (single-threaded apartment)."}

Então continuei as pesquisas e consegui [este projeto](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Converting-between-RTF-and-aaa02a6e).

Fiz o download da Solution, compilei o projeto Class Library, copiei a DLL (MarkupConverter.dll)
para o meu projeto, onde fiz a devida referência, e tentei sua utilização da seguinte forma:

```
IMarkupConverter markupConverter;
markupConverter = new MarkupConverter.MarkupConverter();
var rtfResult = markupConverter.ConvertHtmlToRtf(meuHtml);
```

Mas obtive o seguinte erro:

> {"O thread de chamada deve ser STA, porque muitos componentes da
>   Interface do Usuário assim o exigem."}

Realizei diversas pesquisas, mas não encontrei nada prático e **gratuito** para realizar a conversão do HTML para o RTF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infelizmente, não existem bons conversores open sources... Até agora o unico disponivel é qual voce utilizou que é [este projeto](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Converting-between-RTF-and-aaa02a6e).

No caso ocorreu esse erro pois a conversão utiliza o RichTextBox do WPF que requer uma single threaded apartment (STA). Então ele precisa estar rodando em STA, nos casos de ASP.NET, você não consegue rodar em STA, então seria necessário criar uma thread STA para rodar a conversão.

```
MarkupConverter markupConverter = new MarkupConverter(); 


private string ConvertRtfToHtml(string rtfText) 
{ 
   var thread = new Thread(ConvertRtfInSTAThread); 
   var threadData = new ConvertRtfThreadData { RtfText = rtfText }; 
   thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); 
   thread.Start(threadData); 
   thread.Join(); 
   return threadData.HtmlText; 
} 

private void ConvertRtfInSTAThread(object rtf) 
{ 
   var threadData = rtf as ConvertRtfThreadData; 
   threadData.HtmlText = markupConverter.ConvertRtfToHtml(threadData.RtfText); 
} 


private class ConvertRtfThreadData 
{ 
   public string RtfText { get; set; } 
   public string HtmlText { get; set; } 
}
```

Todas essas informações estão no link anterior. Em forma de documentação.

Comment: Muito obrigado, bastei alterar algumas coisas no código, pois este que você usou se refere a conversão do RTF para HTML, e eu preciso do oposto... Mas 100% funcionando aqui! Eu não havia entendido bem a documentação.

Comment: Deixo apenas uma observação, essa biblioteca por algum motivo não consegue converter `&oacute;` e `&Oacute;` para os seus correspondentes em RTF, mas consegui fazer funcionar fazendo um Replace antes da conversão. `html.Replace("&oacute;", "ó");`