# Converter RTF para HTML

Tags: javascript, c#

Preciso converter o conteúdo RTF de uma string para HTML, em JavaScript ou C#, mas todas as APIs que encontrei no GitHub ou não tinham informações suficientes para a implementação ou tinham algum erro. Então, estou em busca de um "função avulsa", sem que eu precise fazer download de vários arquivos...

Comment: já tentou esse: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Converting-between-RTF-and-aaa02a6e

Comment: esse também, inclusive foi marcado como resposta: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27431/Writing-Your-Own-RTF-Converter . Uma função avulsa acho que não tem como, até porque não é uma coisa tão simples... você pode depois fazer uma função avulsa, mas por trás dela vai ter bastante coisa pra obter tal resultado

Comment: pelo nuget, tem alguns também: https://www.nuget.org/packages/RtfPipe/0.7.0.2 e https://www.nuget.org/packages/sautinsoft.rtftohtml/6.1.12.20

Comment: Consegui com o primeiro que você citou, mas deu um erro que consegui corrigir com a resposta desta pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/114058/como-converter-html-para-rtf